# Allow the user to continue entering numbers until they choose to quit

Tags: java, recursion

This program's objective is to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number. How do I allow the user to continue entering numbers until they choose to quit? Thanks.

```
public class FibonacciNUmbers
 {

 public static int calcFibNum(int x)
 {
  if (x == 0)
    return 0;
  else if (x == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return calcFibNum(x-1) + calcFibNum(x-2);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("What number would you like to find the Fibonacci number for?");
  int x = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("The Fibonacci number of " + x + " is " + calcFibNum(x));

  System.out.println("Would you like to find the Fibonaci number of another number?");
  String answer = in.next();
  if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
  {
      System.out.println("What number would you like to find the Fibonacci number for?");
      x = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("The Fibonacci number for " + x + " is " + calcFibNum(x));
  }

  else 
  {
    System.out.println();
  }

}
```

}

Comment: put it in a while loop

Comment: Change the `if` to `while`  :)

Comment: Wouldn't i need to add a for loop with the while loop as well?

Comment: No, let me give you a rough idea in an answer...one sec

Comment: why do you think that?

Comment: No. Adding the while will suffice and allow you to remove the repeated prompts.

Comment: This has been asked **literally hundreds of times** not only on StackExchange, but the internet. Please, do a search next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//start your while loop here
while (true)
{
    System.out.println("Would you like to find the Fibonacci number of another number?");
    String answer = in.next();
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
    {
        System.out.println("What number would you like to find the Fibonacci number for?");
        x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The Fibonacci number for " + x + " is " + calcFibNum(x));
    }
    else 
    {
      System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
      break; // ends the while loop.
    }
}
```

For loops are used when you can count things or have a set of things.  While loops are used when you're not sure how long it might go on for, or if you want it to continue until some event occurs (user pressing a certain letter for example)

Slight variation of the above that is probly a bit more elegant:

```
String answer = "Y";
//start your while loop here
while (answer.equals("Y")) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to find the Fibonacci number of another number?");
    answer = in.next(); //declare your variable answer outside the loop so you  can use it in the evaluation of how many times to do the loop.
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
    {
        System.out.println("What number would you like to find the Fibonacci number for?");
        x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The Fibonacci number for " + x + " is " + calcFibNum(x));
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
        // no need to break out.
    }
}
```

Comment: On question, why do you use Boolean.TRUE instead of just true?

Comment: @JClassic No reason in particular.  Habit I guess for when I write code like that.  true works just as well and is less typing.

Answer (score 2):

By the way your code prints all the Fibonacci numbers up to n and not the nth number.Below is just an example of how to keep entering input from Scanner. Use that to build upon what you want to do:

```
int num = 0;
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
num = in.nextInt();
}
```

Happy coding!